# SQL Incorrect syntax: CREATE VIEW must be the only statement in the batch

Tags: sql-server, view, create-view

I'm struggling with a problem in SQL - I keep getting this error:

> Incorrect syntax: CREATE VIEW must be the only statement in the batch

I'm using newest Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

```
CREATE VIEW [name] 
AS
    SELECT
        Dostawcy.Nazwa_Firmy,
        Dostawcy.Szef_Imie,
        Dostawcy.Szef_Nazwisko,
        Towary.Nazwa,
        SUM(Towary_Dostawy.Ilosc) AS Suma
    FROM 
        Dostawcy
    INNER JOIN 
        Dostawy ON Dostawcy.Nazwa_Firmy = Dostawy.Firma_Dostarczajaca
    INNER JOIN 
        Towary_Dostawy ON Dostawy.ID_Dostawy = Towary_Dostawy.ID_Dostawy
    INNER JOIN 
        Towary ON Towary_Dostawy.ID_Towaru = Towary.ID_Towaru
    WHERE 
        Towary_Dostawy.ID_Towaru = 4
    GROUP BY
        Towary_Dostawy.ID_Towaru, Towary.Nazwa,
        Dostawcy.Nazwa_Firmy, Dostawcy.Szef_Imie,
        Dostawcy.Szef_Nazwisko
    ORDER BY 
        Suma DESC 

SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM name
```

I checked if the `CREATE VIEW` was at the beginning of the code, tried something with GO, but maybe wrong.

Comment: Please provide the actual version of SQL server - "newest" will be incorrect when the next version comes out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `go` to the line above `select top 1 * from [name]`

Edit: also, the order by should be removed as it has no effect inside of a view.

Comment: Glad it worked! If  the above solves your problem, please mark it as the answer so that others can reference it for help in the future!